# view function() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: django

I'm pretty new to Django, and I've spent hours trying possible solutions to this.
My view takes a kwarg:

```
def inventory(request, id):
    model = Inventory
    # thing = Inventory.objects.get(pk=id) 
    if request.method == "POST":
        stuff = Inventory.objects.get(id=id)
        form = InventoryForm(data = request.POST, instance=stuff) 
        if form.is_valid():
            # if Inventory.filter(item='item').exists()
            # obj = form.save(commit=False)
            form.save()

    else:
        stuff = Inventory.objects.get(id=id)
        form = InventoryForm(instance=stuff)
    context = RequestContext(request)
    return render_to_response('inventory.html', {
            'form':form, 'stuff':stuff
            }, RequestContext(request))
```

When I try the following url pattern:

```
 url(r'^inventory/(?P<id>\d+)/$', inventory, kwargs=dict(model=models.Inventory) name ='inventory'),
```

I get a 404.

This url pattern:

```
url(r'^inventory/$', inventory, name='inventory'),
```

Gives me the following error:

inventory() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

What is the correct syntax here?

Edited to add that this url was working until I added the code allowing the user to edit in addition to add content.

ETA traceback from the new error I get when trying the suggestions below:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/inventory/16/

Django Version: 1.8
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_tables2',
 'camp')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /Users/rebeccaeliserobbins/Documents/repos/djangoBurnApp/bioluminati/camp/templates/base.html, error at line 58
   Reverse for 'inventory' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['inventory/(?P<id>\\d+)/$']

   48 :                 </ul>



   49 :               </li>



   50 :               <li><a href="#">Setup and Exedus</a>



   51 :                 <ul>



   52 :                   <li><a href="#">Sign up for shifts</a></li>



   53 :                   <li><a href="#">Instructions and plans for setup</a></li>



   54 :                 </ul>   



   55 :               </li>



   56 :               <li><a href="#">Operations</a>



   57 :                 <ul>



   58 :                   <li><a href= {% url 'inventory' %} >Truck Inventory</a></li>



   59 :                   <li><a href="#">Budget </a></li>



   60 :                 </ul>



   61 :               </li>



   62 :                



   63 :               {%else %}



   64 :               <li><a href="login">Login</a></li>



   65 :               <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>



   66 :               <li><a href="#">Join us</a></li>



   67 :               {% endif %}



   68 :               <li><a href="#">Resources</a>


Traceback:
File "/Users/rebeccaeliserobbins/Documents/repos/djangoBurnApp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/rebeccaeliserobbins/Documents/repos/djangoBurnApp/bioluminati/camp/views.py" in inventory
  182.     return render(request, 'inventory.html', {'form': form, 'stuff': stuff})
File "/Users/rebeccaeliserobbins/Documents/repos/djangoBurnApp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  67.             template_name, context, request=request, using=using)
File "/Users/rebeccaeliserobbins/Documents/repos/djangoBurnApp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  99.         return template.render(context, request)
File "/Users/rebeccaeliserobbins/Documents/repos/djangoBurnApp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  74.         return self.template.render(context)
File "/Users/rebeccaeliserobbins/Documents/repos/djangoBurnApp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  209.                     return self._render(context)
File "/Users/rebeccaeliserobbins/Documents/repos/djangoBurnApp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  201.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/rebeccaeliserobbins/Documents/repos/djangoBurnApp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Users/rebeccaeliserobbins/Documents/repos/djangoBurnApp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/Users/rebeccaeliserobbins/Documents/repos/djangoBurnApp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  135.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/Users/rebeccaeliserobbins/Documents/repos/djangoBurnApp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  201.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/rebeccaeliserobbins/Documents/repos/djangoBurnApp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Users/rebeccaeliserobbins/Documents/repos/djangoBurnApp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/Users/rebeccaeliserobbins/Documents/repos/djangoBurnApp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  329.                 return nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/rebeccaeliserobbins/Documents/repos/djangoBurnApp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Users/rebeccaeliserobbins/Documents/repos/djangoBurnApp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/Users/rebeccaeliserobbins/Documents/repos/djangoBurnApp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  507.                         six.reraise(*exc_info)
File "/Users/rebeccaeliserobbins/Documents/repos/djangoBurnApp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  493.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
File "/Users/rebeccaeliserobbins/Documents/repos/djangoBurnApp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  579.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
File "/Users/rebeccaeliserobbins/Documents/repos/djangoBurnApp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  496.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /inventory/16/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'inventory' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['inventory/(?P<id>\\d+)/$'
```

]

Comment: How are you calling this url?

Answer (score 3):

This pattern: `url(r'^inventory/(?P<id>\d+)/$', inventory, kwargs=dict(model=models.Inventory) name ='inventory'),` is showing a 404 because you need to go to the URL with an object ID that exists - e.g. `<site>.com/inventory/1`

The second way you are trying doesn't work because `url(r'^inventory/$', inventory, name='inventory'),` does not capture an `id` argument (via `(?P<id>\d+)`), but is expected in your view (`def inventory(request, id):`).

So here is the proper rework, and I cleaned up the code a bit as well for you:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def inventory(request, id):
    if request.method == "GET":
        stuff = Inventory.objects.get(id=id)
        form = InventoryForm(instance=stuff)

    if request.method == "POST":
        stuff = Inventory.objects.get(id=id)
        form = InventoryForm(data=request.POST, instance=stuff) 
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    return render(request, 'inventory.html', {'form': form, 'stuff': stuff})
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^inventory/(?P<id>\d+)/$', inventory, name='inventory'),
```

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. How do I pass in the id argument though?

Comment: It happens automatically when you navigate to the page in your browser, so if you go to `http://<site>.com/inventory/12`, `def inventory()` will be passed `id=12`

Comment: Thanks for this, but I'm still getting a 404 from that url pattern:  url(r'^inventory/(?P<id>\d+)/$', inventory, name='inventory'),

Comment: 404 is most likely happening because it can't find that specific object, meaning you don't have an Inventory object with ID 12. Go to your admin panel, navigate to editing an Inventory object, and look at the URL bar for the Inventory number you are editing. Take that number, and then input it at the end of this URL: `http://<site>.com/inventory/`

Comment: I'm getting a new error (progress?): Reverse for 'inventory' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['inventory/(?P<id>\\d+)/$'].  This is from my navigation bar: {% url 'inventory' %}. Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: Paste the traceback in your original post and I'll take a look. Definitely progress though.